# Hemiacetal formation mechanism

Tags: reaction-mechanism, alcohols

[image]

[image]

The question is asking which reagents can be used to carry out this reaction. I get the L (PCC) is used to turn the primary alcohol into an aldehyde. However, I believe that is not the only reagent needed as the tertiary alcohol -OH must become -O- for the reaction to be SN2. A strong nucleophile is needed to carry out the formation of the SN2 reaction that forms the ring as the aldehyde is only primary (thus SN2 needed). I think that J, the tertbutoxide or S (NaOH) will deprotonate the OH group on the tertiary alcohol for the reaction to proceed.

Why is only L needed and not L and J (or S)?

Comment: The presence of acid in L make the smooth hemiacetal formation.

Comment: There's no SN2 process here. A nucleophile attacking an electrophile doesn't necessarily mean SN2; it's only SN2 if the electrophile is an alkyl halide (amongst other conditions).